# Return Pointer of any selected index in circular singly linked list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I designed this code so that I can get a pointer of any position that user wants in a circular singly linked list, I am using cout to return pointer, I want such a mechanism that I can use it with my other function instead of re writing the whole code again, for that I need to do something with return type which is void right now

Here is the function ..

```
void pointer_to_node(int index){
    Node*temptr;
    temptr = new Node;
    temptr = firstptr;

    Node*temptr2;
    temptr2 = new Node;
    temptr2 = NULL;
    int count = 1;

    while (temptr!=temptr2){
        if(count==index){
            cout << "Required Pointer is : ";
            cout<< temptr;}

        count++;
        temptr2=firstptr;
        temptr=temptr->nextptr;
    }

    if (index>size_of_list())
    {
        temptr=NULL;
        cout<< "Can't You think in bounds. Take your NULL Pointer ";
        cout << temptr;
        delete temptr;
        delete temptr2;
    }
}
```

Comment: make it return the `Node *` that you end up on

Comment: also granted I haven't read this at all, but what is the point of bounds checking in a circular LL?

Comment: @AK4749 `index %= size_of_list()` :)

Comment: @AK4749 actually i have given an option of adding the nodes to user, if he has added just 3 nodes and requesting a pointer of 4th node , than i am giving a NULL POINTER, 


okay now i changed it to 

Node* pointer_to_node(int index)

but its still giving errors and not returning any thing


\warning: control reaches end of non-void function|
\

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return a `Node *`.

However, while you're doing that, you also really need to take out these: `temptr = new Node;` lines, as well as the `delete`s, as you're leaking memory there. You just immediately discard those new nodes by reassigning the pointers. The `delete`s at the end will delete the wrong nodes entirely, and aren't called in all cases anyway.

And if you pass an index of 0, your loop might take a very long time indeed.

I assume you have good reason for wanting to return NULL if you loop around the list.

Something like the following should suffice:

```
Node *pointer_to_node(int index)
{
    Node *temp = firstptr;
    while(index-- != 0) {
        temp = temp->nextPtr;
        if(temp == firstptr) return NULL;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: its stilll not returning ??? 

i changed the return type to 


    Node pointer_to_node(int index)

and the error i receive is


   |82|error: conversion from `Node*' to non-scalar type `Node' requested|

Comment: The return type should be Node*, not Node.

Comment: i first changed it to NODE* and forgot to write cout .. done .. THanks... how should i vote your answer